# Bower Failed to execute git clone

Tags: asp.net-mvc, git, bower

I am trying to import the jPlayer package through bower in an asp.net application however I get this error code every time:

> ECMDERR Failed to execute "git clone https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer.git -b 2.9.2 --progress . --depth 1", exit code of #-532462766

Does anyone know what the issue is and if it is my end? The rest of my imports work just fine.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery-ui": "^1.11.4",
    "jquery-validate": "^1.15.0",
    "jquery-ajax-unobtrusive": "^3.2.4",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.6",
    "select2": "^4.0.2",
    "dropzone": "^4.3.0",
    "jplayer": "*", // Fails
    "font-awesome": "^4.5.0"
  },
    "name": "test",
    "private": true,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "authors": [
        "Martin Dawson"
    ],
    "description": "test",
    "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Remove the `.` between `--progress` and `--depth 1`.

Comment: @ElpieKay I can't remove it, bower automatically generates that line of code and I don't know why it's putting the dot there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of specifying the package name in bower.json I ran the command `bower install https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer.git --save`.

This generated this in bower.json:

```
"jPlayer": "https://github.com/happyworm/jPlayer.git#^2.9.2"
```

This worked for me. Figured it out thanks to Elpie. Don't know why bower.json was generating the wrong git clone.